# Android how to get an ancestor view from a child view?

Tags: android, onclick, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

I have a list of type `Foo` with a custom array Adapter. I want to be able to click on a child element in one of the views in the array adapter and get back the view I clicked on of type `Foo`.

This is how I am clicking on a child element:

```
// fill array with a test set of objects
final ArrayList<Foo> locations = Foo.getTestingList();

final myCustomArrayAdapter adapter = new myCustomArrayAdapter(rootView.getContext(), myarrayList);
         adapter.setDefaultRequestBtnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                    //if child element is clicked
                    if(v.getId() == R.id.deleteBTN){
                        //tag is set to the position in my custom adapter
                        int pos = (Integer)v.getTag();

                       //Get this child's parent view (type foo)


                    }

             }
         });
```

I want to be able to use certain `Foo` methods on the `Foo`parent of the child View I just clicked on.

Comment: It's not entirely clear of what you want. The view you clicked is provided to you as the singular argument of the onClick(View) callback. You may need to cast it to the appropriate type if you have a custom view, or you may need to iterate over its child views if it's a ViewGroup and it first intercepts the touch-events on behalf of its children.

Comment: @WadeWilson the View in onClick(View) is a child element (button) in my Foo view because I clicked on a particular button inside my custom View Foo. I am not sure on how to get its parent/ .container which is of type Foo

Comment: There is a method called getParent() on the View class, the return type is ViewParent but you can cast the return value to your "Foo" type. (For safety, wrap it in an instanceof check)

Comment: @WadeWilson but getParent() will give me the outermost container, which in my case is not Foo. Foo is located inside the outermost container which is a constraint View in my case.

Comment: I guess my generic question would be how to get any parent/grandparent/great-grandparent... etc from any child view within the line.

Comment: Have you debugged the code and verified that getParent() returns the topmost container view and not the direct parent? Could you post your XML layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198181/discussion-between-user7331538-and-wade-wilson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna get the direct parent of a view, you can call the method [getParent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent()) and it will return immediate parent of the target view. Note, this method doesn't directly return a view but instead a [ViewParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html). ViewParent does not technically need to be a View but all views capable of holding child views i.e. a "view parent" in the Android SDK are of type [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) which itself implements the ViewParent. So in reality virtually all ViewParents are a ViewGroup, which in itself is a View.

Furthermore, if you wanna access an ancestor view that's beyond the direct parent, you can recursively call getParent() and perform checks on the return parent view to determine if they are the desired view.